# How can I build a custom kendo ui theme?

Tags: kendo-ui

If I go here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/, I get a message saying the page would like to load insecure content and the controls aren't rendered.

[image]

Once I get passed that and I select Customise theme, the controls render, but there doesn't seem to be a way to customize a theme.

[image]

How can I build a custom kendo ui theme?